# Return from function as argument

Tags: c

At the moment when Create returns I don't have the new error code.

```
typedef union {
    u8* ErrorCode_u16;
} Param;



void Create(void* params)
{
    Param *parameters = (Param*)params;

    parameters[1].ErrorCode_u16 = Foo();
}
```

When Create return I would like to have the new error code in my array of void pointers.

Just to mention

> How can I do it ?

Comment: What is `Foo`? What does it do? Can't you just return a pointer from it? Can you please elaborate on the problem you have? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you pass `void*` when you know you're dealing with `Param*`...

Comment: Yes .. good qestion. Why do I pass void ? ... That is left from a previus implementation that did not work. thanks

Comment: Show much more context, i.e. make a [mcve]. Have it contain comments with pseudo code where you do not have any clue.

Comment: Are you sure that `void* params` is an array of `Param` with at least 2 elements?

Comment: The cast is redundant.

Comment: I don't see the problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this

```
Param data[2/* or more */];
Create(data);
/* data[1] has the result of Foo() call */
```